# MS Access Group By number of distinct items in column

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have this table below:

```
AgentCode | Status 
-----------------------
Agent1    | Registered
Agent1    | Rejected
Agent2    | Registered
```

And I need to write a MS Access query to get this output:

```
AgentCode | Registered | Rejected | Total
-----------------------------------------
Agent1    | 1          | 1        | 2
Agent2    | 1          | 0        | 1
```

I know a GROUP BY statement should do this but somehow I'm lost in trying to write the query itself.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `GROUP BY` won't do that. You want a crosstab query.

Comment: I just tried the crosstab query and it did return the AgentCode and the total count of items under the specific AgentCode. But would you know how I can segregate the total (per status) as the sample above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT AgentCode
    ,SUM(IFF(Status='Registered',1,0)) as Registered
    ,SUM(IFF(Status='Rejected',1,0)) as Rejected
    ,Count(Status) as Total
FROM table
GROUP BY AgentCode
```

Comment: Just changed the "IFF" from the post above to "IIF". Other than that, it's really awesome. Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it both with a **GROUP BY query** (as shown by Dimitris):

```
SELECT
  AgentCode,
  SUM(IIF(Status='Registered',1,0)) AS Registered,
  SUM(IIF(Status='Rejected'  ,1,0)) AS Rejected,
  COUNT(  Status                  ) AS Total
FROM table
GROUP BY AgentCode
```

...or with a **CROSSTAB query** like this:

```
TRANSFORM COUNT(Status) 
SELECT AgentCode, Count(Status) AS Total
FROM table
GROUP BY AgentCode
PIVOT Status
```

There are differences, though.

1. **static vs dynamic** - The GROUP BY query is static, while the CROSSTAB query is dynamic. That means that if you start using different statuses, or you filter with a where and have less statuses, the former will not adapt the columns, while the latter will.
2. **Portability** -  The GROUP BY query is very similar to what you can do on most RDBMS (except for the IIF function, that in other RDBMS must be susbstituted with a CASE WHEN). The CROSSTAB query is not very standard. It is implemented on many RDBMS, but with very different syntaxes.